# Portractor tests are not running in a new window

Tags: protractor

I am a protractor automation tester and fairly new to it. 
When I am running protractor tests, it's always open in a new tab but I want them to open in new window. Does anybody has solution for it?

Comment: Can you share your protractor.conf.js file?

Comment: When you use protractor to click on anything, it won't change web app original behavior to open in new tab or window. Protractor just click it,  the developer code determine open in new or current  tab/window. Protractor can't determine the app how to action next after click.